# Kundera and Cassandra unit issue - String as primary key

Tags: cassandra, kundera

I have a kundera model entity which has String as the Id. It is defined like this.

```
@Id
private String id;
```

I have a method where I am executing native query like this.

```
/**
     * @param requestId
     * @return
     */
    public static ProcessRequest getRequest(Serializable requestId) {
        List<ProcessRequest> requests = execute("SELECT * from
            process_requests where id = '" + requestId + "';");
        return requests.isEmpty() ? null : requests.get(0);
    }
```

I am getting the following exception when running the unit tests like this.

```
17:50:38.716 [main] ERROR c.i.c.cassandra.CassandraClientBase - Error during executing query SELECT * from process_requests where id = '5b4468e0-6146-4fbc-81cf-571371834446';, Caused by: {} .
com.impetus.kundera.KunderaException: InvalidRequestException(why:Undefined name id in where clause ('id EQ '5b4468e0-6146-4fbc-81cf-571371834446''))
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.CassandraClientBase.execute(CassandraClientBase.java:2101) [kundera-cassandra-2.14.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.CassandraClientBase.executeCQLQuery(CassandraClientBase.java:1708) [kundera-cassandra-2.14.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.CassandraClientBase$CQLClient.executeQuery(CassandraClientBase.java:1851) [kundera-cassandra-2.14.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.CassandraClientBase.executeSelectQuery(CassandraClientBase.java:761) [kundera-cassandra-2.14.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClient.executeQuery(ThriftClient.java:860) [kundera-cassandra-2.14.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.client.cassandra.query.CassQuery.populateEntities(CassQuery.java:143) [kundera-cassandra-2.14.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryImpl.fetch(QueryImpl.java:1013) [kundera-core-2.14.jar:na]
    at com.impetus.kundera.query.QueryImpl.getResultList(QueryImpl.java:164) [kundera-core-2.14.jar:na]
```

Even if there is a column defined by id, it is giving this exception and I have for help exhaustively and could not solve it. Can you please help to solve this?

Update:

```
CREATE TABLE docyard.process_requests (
id text PRIMARY KEY,
content_type text,
created_at timestamp,
document_id text,
lock bigint,
lock_expiration timestamp,
namespace text,
process_input text,
process_output text,
processed text,
updated_at timestamp,
version_id text
) WITH bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01
AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'
AND comment = ''
AND compaction = {'min_threshold': '4', 'class':           'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy',       'max_threshold': '32'}
AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}
AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1
AND default_time_to_live = 0
AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000
AND max_index_interval = 2048
AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0
AND min_index_interval = 128
AND read_repair_chance = 0.0
AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
CREATE INDEX process_requests_lock_idx ON docyard.process_requests  (lock);
CREATE INDEX process_requests_processed_idx ON docyard.process_requests (processed);
```

Comment: *Searched for help exhaustively

Comment: Open up a cqlsh session on your cassandra cluster, and edit your answer to include the output of `desc table process_requests`.

Comment: I have added the table description in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using CQL2 for creating your schema, primary key column with any name is created with name `'key'`.

This is handled by Kundera if you are using `createQuery` or `findById`. Since you are using `native query` change `where id = ...` to `where key = ...`

PS: CQL3 is preferred while working with Kundera. You can refer [this](https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/wiki/Native-CQL3-to-object-mapping) for more info about CQL3.

Comment: Hi, I am using cql3 only. The query works fine when the application is run normally but not when it is run with the cassandra unit.

Comment: It worked after using the 'key' keyword but the same is not working when i run the application normally, its working only with the embedded cassandra. Any way to solve it?

Comment: Are you sure you are not using CQL2-CQL3 interchangeably for creating and retrieving data?

Comment: I am using CQL3 itself, no where I am mentioning CQL2.. So I had to mock the query dynamically to use 'key' when running cassandra unit..